# Input value is not being cleared after submit

Tags: reactjs, submit

I am building a to-do list in react and when adding a new task to the list, the input value is not being cleared from the form after submit, I'm trying to achieve this using `setInput('');`

```
const Form = (props) => {

  const [input, setInput] = useState('');

  const handleChange = e => {
    setInput(e.target.value);
  }

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newTask = {
      id: uuidv4(),
      text: input,
      completed: false
    };

    props.onSubmit(newTask);
    setInput('');
  }

  return (
    <form
      className='task-form'
      >
      <input
        className='task-input'
        type='text'
        placeholder='Enter a task'
        name='text'
        onChange={handleChange}
        />
      <button className='task-btn' onClick={handleSubmit}>Add Task</button>
    </form>
  )
}

export default Form
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't using the `input` state anywhere except when creating the `newTask` object. You need to pass it as a prop to the `<input>` component to make it fully controlled and for calls to the state setter to result in changes to the DOM.

```
  <input
    className='task-input'
    type='text'
    placeholder='Enter a task'
    name='text'
    onChange={handleChange}
    />
```

should be

```
  <input
    className='task-input'
    type='text'
    placeholder='Enter a task'
    name='text'
    onChange={handleChange}
    value={input}
    />
```